# How to query several MongoDB collections at once?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

For example, I have two collections `A` and `B` and I have a `find()` query per each collection with unrelated data to return.
What I need is to combine these two query results and execute `limit()` and `skip()` operations. Executing these two queries sequentially is a pretty complex task.

Comment: You can send the two query requests at the same time - then process the completed query results.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Is there any link between these two collections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can do something like that :

```
const [docs1, docs2] = await Promise.all([
      Model1.find().skip().limit().exec(),
      Model2.find().skip().limit().exec()
])
```